# ERROR: cannot verify dl.google.com's certificate, issued by

Tags: networking, apt, google-chrome, ssl

I want to install google Chrome in Ubuntu 18.04. I tried:

```
sudo wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

But I get an error:

> Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|216.58.201.46|:443...
>   connected. ERROR: cannot verify dl.google.com's certificate, issued by
>   ‘CN=Google Internet Authority G3,O=Google Trust Services,C=US’:
>   Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority. To connect to
>   dl.google.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

I searched on posts about similar issue. Some of the suggestions:

```
apt-get install ca-certificates
apt-get install ssl-cert
```

But did not help.

How to solve the issue and install Chrome safely without ignore the certificate as I want secure installation.